# How to create a nested query using sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm trying to write a nested query using sqldf. The dataset is 'contact_fb'. I am trying to only take rows without clubmahindra and  distinct names which are in column 'from_name' and then left join with the 'contact_fb ' to get all the info in the other columns. This is giving not the result I want:

```
contact_fb =structure(list(X = 1:6, from_name = c("Club Mahindra", "Club Mahindra","pinto", "valencia", "valencia", "Club Mahindra"), type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("link","photo", "status", "video"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X","from_name", "type"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My attempt at this is:

```
names_cm=sqldf("select t1.from_name, t2.* from (select distinct from_name from  contact_fb where from_name!='Club Mahindra') as t1 left join  ( select * from contact_fb ) as t2 on t1.from_name=t2.t1.from_name")
```

I could get it finally through

```
sqldf("select distinct(t1.from_name),t2.* from df t1 left join df t2 on (t1.from_name=t2.from_name) where t1.from_name!='Club Mahindra' group by t1.from_name")
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Could I still get it through my way?

The output is:

```
3   Pinto   photo
4   valencia    link
```

Comment: take a closer look at your query, you did not select anything from the table.

Comment: Please explain in words what you are trying to do and show the expected output.

Comment: @ thanks MIke Fang i could get it working but it is still not giving the reqd results.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck It will be lot clearer now i hope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output shown at the end of the question seems to be the set of distinct `from_name`, `type` pairs for which `from_name` is not `"Club Mahindra"` and for that we don't need a join:

```
sqldf("select distinct from_name, type 
       from contact_fb 
       where from_name != 'Club Mahindra'")
```

giving:

```
  from_name  type
1     pinto photo
2  valencia  link
```

Comment: I didnt wanted to do this way since i have to write the names of all variable so i was trying to join it taking distinct values and the rest of info.

Comment: `select distinct * from ...` would do it with all variables.

Comment: that would give me. there would be extra valenica. `X from_name  type`
`1 3     pinto photo`
`2 4  valencia  link`
`3 5  valencia  link`

Comment: Yes, because there is not a unique `X` for that combination of `from_name` and `type` so it gives each one.  If you just want to pick out an arbitrary `X` then you could try: `sqldf("select * 
       from contact_fb 
       where from_name != 'Club Mahindra'
       group by from_name, type")` or maybe just `group by from_name` depending on what it is you want.

Comment: yeah this will do. i was just trying to make this more complicated that it was. thanks for your help.